# Access a select option and input text just on first row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to manipulated a select option and input text area on a table. The code looked like this :

```
<table id="list2" class="table table-bordered>

   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th style="width:15%">Item</th>
         <th style="width:22.5%">Remarks</th>
         <th style="width:10%">Manhour</th>
         <th>Act</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
     <tr class="list2_var">
        <td>
          <select class="form-control cleaning-item" name="list2_cleaning_item_0" id="list2_cleaning_item_0">
             <option disabled="" selected="">Pilih</option>
             <option value="01">Certificate</option> 
             <option value="02">Interior</option>
             <option value="03">Exterior</option>
             <option value="04">Foreign Marking</option>                                            
          </select>
         </td>


        <td>
         <input class="form-control remarks" name="list_2_remarks_0" placeholder="Remarks" id="list_2_remarks_0" type="text">
        </td>

        <td>
         <input class="form-control" name="list_2_manhour_0" placeholder="Manhour" type="text">
        </td>

        <td class="del_area04">
          <button style="display: none;" class="list2_del btn btn-block btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

If I have many row, how to access and manipulated the class `cleaning-item` and `remarks` just on first row. Why I should do it, coz I use jquery-input-area which is dynamic input from this [link](http://www.usamimi.info/~sutara/sample/add-input-area/).

The success of my ajax looked like this :

```
$('#list2 td .remarks').val('example');
$('#list2 td .cleaning-item').val('02');
```

But it will manipulated all the row. How can I make it just on first row, after then, both of them will be disable just on first row??
Any help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to select the first row

Using *:eq()*

```
$('#list2 tbody tr:eq(0) td .remarks').val('example');
$('#list2 td tr:eq(0) .cleaning-item').val('02');
```

Or using *.eq()*

```
$('#list2 tbody tr').eq(0).find('td .remarks').val('example');
$('#list2 td tr').eq(0).find('.cleaning-item').val('02');
```

Or using *:first*

```
$('#list2 tbody tr:first td .remarks').val('example');
$('#list2 td tr:first .cleaning-item').val('02');
```

Or using *.first()*

```
$('#list2 tbody tr').first().find('td .remarks').val('example');
$('#list2 td tr').first().find('.cleaning-item').val('02');
```

Comment: what is `first(0)` ? Looks like a copy/paste error from `eq(0)`

Comment: @charlietfl it is `first()` :)

Answer (score 0):

use `:first`  selector   or `.first()` jquery

```
tr:first
```

or

```
$('tr').first()
```